# Passing storage location to factory function vs storing it yourself

Tags: design, design-patterns

I have run across a bunch of code where they are essentially doing

```
void CreateFoo(string foo_param_1, int foo_param_2, vector<Foo> *foo_storage) {
    Foo new_foo = FooFactory();
    new_foo.set_param_1(foo_param_1);
    new_foo.set_param_2(foo_param_2);
    foo_storage->push_back(new_foo);
}
```

To me this seems like a horrible design because now there is a mixing of concerns in the creation and storage of `Foo`s. Is this a common practice? If so, can someone explain why it's good?

My instinct is that it should be

```
Foo CreateFoo(string foo_param_1, int foo_param_2) {
    Foo new_foo = FooFactory();
    new_foo.set_param_1(foo_param_1);
    new_foo.set_param_2(foo_param_2);
    return new_foo;
}

foo_storage.push_back(CreateFoo("hello", 10));
```

Comment: If you consider two lines of a code in a method to be a 'mixing of concerns', then how do you ever write functions more than one line long?

Comment: @17of26 apparently it was not clear that I was trying to cut down on lines for the sake of an example

Comment: Ok, that's better.

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible to answer something like this in isolation. Whether it makes sense to have an API like the existing CreateFoo depends on how that API is used in practice.

Your rewrite is almost CERTAINLY worse, however. CreateFoo is then a foo-factory, as is 'FooFactory'. What was the value added in your CreateFoo function?

Perhaps there is no value in ANY CreateFoo function, and you should just write:

```
foo_storage.push_back(FooFactory("hello", 10));
```

My $0.02....

Comment: I've updated things to be closer to what is actually happening, though in reality there is even more that goes into the creation of a `Foo`. In reality there are closer to 7 params that go into the creation of a `Foo` and the creation of one is fairly complicated. After all of that work it seems odd to me to have one line where you stuff it into a container when you could just return it and let people decide what they want to do with it.

Comment: @NickChapman EVEN  NOW, as you've modified the example, I would just add CTOR arguments to FooFactory(), and not introduce another helper function that just pushes data through. Sadly, C++ does not yet support named parameters, so if the number of overloads gets sufficiently complicated, you may need to do something else to construct your foo objects. This really does depend on the details (which you've sensibly omitted) of your example. But if you can sensibly provide all the arguments as optional parameters to FooFactory, my above suggestion still makes sense to me.

Comment: I fully understand what you're saying. Unfortunately, the class being constructed is created by compiling an IDL that doesn't provide a constructor taking any arguments :(

Answer (score 0):

If the design of the system is such that a Foo must always be added to foo_storage after creation, then the first CreateFoo is correct.

By separating the calls, you introduce the possibility of bugs from code calling CreateFoo() and not following up with foo_storage.push_back().